# Migrating data from MSSQL to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, transformation

I have a few tables in SQL Server Express that contain data with high characters - ex: Häagen-Dazs

I've exported SQL inserts and when I run in MySQL they fail on these characters. SQL Express doesn't have DTS so I can't do an ODBC transformation.

I've used FileMaker Pro's external table functionality but the characters show up as odd characters. ex: �

Any tips would be most appreciated.

Comment: First of all: do the INSERT SQL statements you created contain the special characters or just a '?' characters: you need to first establish whether the export process or the import process is going wrong. Do you know what UNICODE (UTF-16, UTF-8 etc) your MySQL is set up to use ? (What Operating system are you running MySQL on?)

Comment: My Collation is latin1_swedish_ci but I guess it should be utf8_geneal_ci?  MySQL is running on Windows, v5.0.90 The data exported from SQL Server looks good - characters are all there. when i run the inserts in mysql it's thru phpmyadmin so maybe php is dorking up the characters.

Comment: I changed collation, re-imported thru filemaker and i see the high characters correctly. They also show in phpmyadmin. when i pull up the data thru my php page it still shows the ? character. my html does state content="text/html; charset=utf-8"

Comment: found a fix...
http://www.toao.net/48-replacing-smart-quotes-and-em-dashes-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

Found a fix

[Replacing Smart Quotes in MySQL](http://www.toao.net/48-replacing-smart-quotes-and-em-dashes-in-mysql)